# Rails / Snow Leopard Mysql 64-bit question

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, 64-bit, osx-snow-leopard, macports

Hey all, I'm trying to install 64-bit MySQL on Snow Leopard for a rails app.

I've installed it from the dmg and I can get to mysql fine from the command line. Based on various blog posts as well as the other topics here on Stack, I shut down mysql, uninstall the mysql gem, and then try to update the gem with the following:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' gem install --verbose --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

That produces the following:

```
GET 200 OK: http://gems.rubyforge.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
Installing gem mysql-2.8.1
Downloading gem mysql-2.8.1.gem
GET 302 Found: http://gems.rubyforge.org/gems/mysql-2.8.1.gem
GET 200 OK: http://s3.amazonaws.com/gemcutter_production/gems/mysql-2.8.1.gem
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/COPYING
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/COPYING.ja
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/History.txt
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/Manifest.txt
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/README.txt
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/Rakefile
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/mysql.c
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/extra/README.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/extra/README_ja.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/extra/tommy.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/tasks/gem.rake
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/tasks/native.rake
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/tasks/vendor_mysql.rake
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/test/test_mysql.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin8.0 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H  -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common -g -O2  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common  -arch i386 -c mysql.c
cc -dynamic -bundle -undefined suppress -flat_namespace -arch i386 -L"/usr/local/lib" -o mysql_api.bundle mysql.o  -lruby -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lm     -lmygcc  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  
ld: warning: in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmygcc.a, file is not of required architecture

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 mysql_api.bundle /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
```

Those two warnings at the end seem ominous. I then go to my rails app and run

```
rake db:migrate
```

And get:

```
dyld: NSLinkModule() error
dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
Trace/BPT trap
```

And that's as far as I'm able to get. I've tried installing MySQL via the dmg and via macports and I seem to run into this error in both cases.

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to rails; any light anyone can shed would be wildly appreciated. Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

In response to John's (and khelll's) answers below:

When I do the first command that John specified, I get:

```
No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table
```

There's about 40 lines of this. I assumed this was because of the documentation. But when I do rake db:migrate I get:

```
dyld: NSLinkModule() error
dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
Trace/BPT trap
```

Using the ARCHFLAGS command produces the error I specified earlier.

--- SECOND EDIT ---

I should add that I did *not* install from source. After peeking at the Hivelogic instructions again, I went down this route.

When I tried to run:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-extra-charsets=complex \
--enable-thread-safe-client --enable-local-infile --enable-shared \
--with-plugins=innobase
```

I got:

```
config.status: creating zlib/Makefile
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/gawk
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
./config.status: line 1782: 69228 Done(141)               eval sed ç"ç$ac_sed_extraç" "$ac_file_inputs"
     69229 Trace/BPT trap
```

So I did:

```
sudo port deactivate gettext
sudo port activate gettext @0.17_3
```

However, after following all the steps, reinstalling the gem, upon rake db:migrate I still get:

```
dyld: NSLinkModule() error
dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
Trace/BPT trap
```

---- THIRD EDIT ----

Okay - I believe what's happening here is that, even though I'm specifying the 64 bit gem above, it's installing the 32 bit version. I do:

```
file /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
```

And get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle: Mach-O bundle i386
```

So it would seem I keep installing the 32 bit version

Answer (score 1):

I installed it from source following [these instructions on Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard) and it works great. Then I installed the MySQL RubyGem using:

`sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql`

Comment: After that install the gem: sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Comment: I didn't need the ARCHFLAGS or config directive.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses.

When I do the first command that John specified, I get tons of "No definition for next_result, No definition for field_name" and so on and so on. I assumed this was because of the documentation. But when I do rake db:migrate I get:

dyld: NSLinkModule() error
dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
Trace/BPT trap


The archflags produces the error I specified above

Comment: So did you actually follow the instructions I linked to for compiling and installing 64-bit MySQL from source?

Comment: Sorry - just added my response up top.